# Why can't ripped movies import to into iTunes on Windows XP when they work on Mac?

Tags: itunes, windows

I am unable to copy movies or videos into my iTunes library. I have had the concerned videos converted using Handbrake (version ??) with Apple presets but still when I try drag and drop to iTunes (10.1 on Windows XP) it shows no error (like "cannot be played" etc) and neither does it show up on the list.

I can copy songs/ebooks/apps got a problem with video only.

So I updated to iTunes v 10.5.3 still can't drag drop video/movies. I even tried adding the files to the **Automatically add to iTunes** folder (as suggested in one of the comments) but got a *Not Added* folder. The files work when copied to the library on a friend's, so I can't tell if the problem is iTunes or Windows XP or my computer.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different.  Before anyone can answer authoritatively, can you clarify exactly what the error message is, and what format you are encoding in with handbrake?

Comment: @stuffe I used the built in preset for iphone 4 and i get no error message at all, i try drag and drop and nothing more, no messages at all (atlest cannot be played in iphone would have been heartening) and [these presets](http://lifehacker.com/5572037/handbrake-presets-for-your-new-ipad-or-iphone-4)

Comment: So the real problem is getting them into iTunes in the first place?  Try the following: 1) can you play the resulting file without importing to iTunes, just double click open it? 2) Check the filename is .m4v not .mp4, iTunes prefers it. 3) Update iTunes to the latest version (cop out, but might help) 4) reset your presets in handbrake, you may have modified one.  Or try Apple Universal too.  I can't really put this as an answer as I'm just guessing right now :)

Comment: @stuffe Right i am not able to get them into iTunes,can play the file, the extension is right and i have tried with all the presets. Could give a try by updating iTunes to the latest !. Do you have any idea as why is it not giving any error if it can't move it to iTunes library maybe i overlooked something.

Comment: I can only guess that there is a problem with your iTunes library database files.  You can test this.  Hold down SHIFT and start iTunes.  It should ask you to create a new library - don't worry, this is *in addition* to your existing one.  Try creating a new one and putting your files in there

Comment: There should be a folder in your iTunes Media folder named "Automatically Add to iTunes". Drop the file in there. I think you definitely need to update to latest version of iTunes as well.

Comment: @afragen Updated to the latest iTunes, i tried your suggestion i then got a folder *Not Added* folder with that video in it , any hints ?

Comment: Do you have QuickTime player on Windows? If so, can it open and play the movie?

Comment: @bneely Yes it does play them

Comment: When I have gotten this _Not Added_ folder it meant there was something not well with the rip. I would re-rip using Handbrake and Apple Universal setting.

Comment: @afragen Could you give the specifications for handbrake(m using the latest 0.9.5)  then which worked for you since none of the presets seems to have worked for me.

Comment: @NewBee - I'm doing the Handbrake conversion on a Mac, also using 0.9.5. What I usually do is find the correct movie title, in using DVD Player or VLC, then do a Title conversion using the Apple Universal preset. Have you _ever_ been able to successfully rip a DVD and add it to iTunes?

Comment: @afragen I have converted existing `.avi` files, one more update the file got added to Itunes in a different persons PC (but he is on Mac) the same didn't work for me, ring any bells ?

Comment: I've always worked with the original DVDs when using Handbrake. I suggest a quick google search, http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+avi+to+itunes&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari#sclient=tablet-gws&hl=en&client=safari&tbo=d&source=hp&q=convert+avi+to+itunes+on+windows&pbx=1&oq=convert+avi+to+itunes+on+windows and use something other than Handbrake. Not sure why it would work on Mac and not PC.

Comment: I've tried to clean this up so it gets some votes and attention. Please let us know if you have solved it (by answering below) or if any of the details in the question can be improved.

Answer (score -1):

I have been facing the same problem with iTunes (both 10.5 and 11). You need to upgrade to iTunes version 10.5 or 11, and you would need Quick Time to play older media or videos.

Comment: It's a bit confusing since you say the problem exists with v11 but the OP should upgrade to version 11. Perhaps you can explain more about reinstalling QuickTime or some other test to help people in this case?